# How to debug Cordova application with Push Capability?

Tags: ios, cordova

I'am develop mobile iOS application with Cordova. While developing application sign's with automatic provisioning profile (my own account, unpaid). I also have distribution profile to create an .ipa distributive (another account, paid).

When application is signing with automatic provisioning profile and deploy on a real device, I can see all debug information in Safari console. But when application is signing with distribution profile I can't see any debug information.

Now it was necessary to use Push capability in application. I want to debug application while develop. But my automatic provisioning profile does not allow deploy on real device with Push capability (because it is unpaid account), and distribution profile does not output any debug information in Safari console. As I understand, to get an opportunity of testing application on real device with push and debug info, need developer profile with push capability. Is I'm right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Evgeniy, yes your understanding is correct.

Pushing your app directly to a device, you may need a apple dev acct with the provision on accessing your device. More info: https://developer.apple.com/support/code-signing/